# Let a and b be real number such that, $a < b + \epsilon $, for every $ \epsilon > 0$. Prove that $ a \leq b$.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let a and b be real number such that, $a < b + \epsilon $, for every $ \epsilon > 0$. Prove that $ a\leq b$.

Comment: And what have you tried? There really doesn't seem much to show here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose on the contrary that $a>b$, then Let $\epsilon=a-b>0$.

Then $b+\epsilon=a$ which is not bigger than $a$.